# Fonts with format ttf are not loaded when I deploy mt react + vite project to vercel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, vite

I have built a vite + reactjs project and I use two fonts that are imported locally in index.css using font-face. everything works just fine in dev mode but when I do the npm run build and deploy my project on CPanel, fonts are not loaded. in the assets folder in the build file I can see the font-faces but for some reason they are not loaded correctly.

fonts are located in `src/fonts`;

index.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "IRANSans";
  src: local("IRANSans") , url("./fonts/IRANSans.ttf"), format('ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Casablanca";
  src: local("Casablanca") ,url("./fonts/Casablanca.ttf"), format('ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

then I import them in main.js(Vite)=> index.js(Reactjs) and everything seems correct but in production mode, fonts are not loaded! :(